# (int)Math.random prints random line of numbers outside of set range for first line

Tags: java, arrays, math, random

Trying to make an array of random numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
randomArray(5);
    }
    public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
        int x=0;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
           x= (int)(Math.random ()*high)+low;
             System.out.print(x);
        }
     return x;       
    }
    public static int[] randomArray(int n){
        int[] a = new int [n];
        for (int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
            a[i]=randomInt (0,100);}
        printArray(a);
        return a;
    }
    public static void printArray (int[]a) {
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    }
}
```

this  returns something along the lines of

```
9265956792478464547638861753937389642303686408882492318499964845942725987325868511898811389
42
49
73
72
```

Which is way, way out of range. Any ideas?

Comment: `System.print()` does not append a newline, so you're just printing a bunch of numbers on the same line.

Comment: Why is there a for-loop in your `randomInt` method? You're making 9 random numbers and throwing them away and returning the tenth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a: `System.out.print(x)` inside `randomInt`.

Comment: To elucidate just a bit, `System.out.print(x)` will print `x` ***with no carriage-return after it***. That line is really `92` `65` `95` `67` etc etc etc.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Must've left that during testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- You had a print statement in your 'randomInt' function
- You had an unnecessary loop in your 'randomInt' function
- You're 'randomInt' function only produced proper results because you were using low=0
- - Ex: high=10; low=5; ((Math.random() * high) + low) would produce results between 5 and 15, not 5 and 10

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        randomArray(5);
    }
    public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
        return (int)(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;       
    }
    public static int[] randomArray(int n){
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = randomInt(0, 100);
        }
        printArray(a);
        return a;
    }
    public static void printArray (int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - I copy and pasted it from http://ideone.com (a web based compiler) that line was in the Java language template that i used to make my example code.